# TinyMCE Toolbar Not Showing Up

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

Hey guys I have been on this for a few hours an im stumped. I set up a distract-free editor on my website, but cant get the toolbar to show up when I click on text.

I appreciate any help, im not sure what it is that im doing wrong and have done extensive research trying to figure this out. So thank you for your time!

Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="post">
<div class='demo-dfree'>
  <h2 class="dfree-header mce-content-body" contenteditable="true" style="position: relative;" spellcheck="false">
    Header
  </h2>
  <br/>
  <div class="dfree-body mce-content-body" contenteditable="true" style="position: relative;" spellcheck="false">
    <p>
     Body
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my script placed in my header:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/79eqkg3mxj7h6alrcmz1yxjsp6fxm1qhdvkrrfy9uxdxwjrf/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>

  <script >
var dfreeHeaderConfig = {
  selector: '.dfree-header',
  menubar: false,
  inline: true,
  toolbar: false,
  plugins: [ 'quickbars' ],
  quickbars_insert_toolbar: 'undo redo',
  quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'italic underline'
};

var dfreeBodyConfig = {
  selector: '.dfree-body',
  menubar: false,
  inline: true,
  plugins: [
    'autolink',
    'codesample',
    'link',
    'lists',
    'media',
    'powerpaste',
    'table',
    'image',
    'quickbars'
  ],
  toolbar: false,
  quickbars_insert_toolbar: 'quicktable image',
  quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | h2 h3 | blockquote quicklink',
  contextmenu: 'inserttable | cell row column deletetable',
  powerpaste_word_import: 'clean',
  powerpaste_html_import: 'clean'
};

tinymce.init(dfreeHeaderConfig);
tinymce.init(dfreeBodyConfig);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my script needed to have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of its page, everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I guess what you want to use is the "Inline Editor" instead of the "Distraction free" one?

Have a look at the official example: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/inline/

---

**EDIT:** Your selectors are wrong. 
In JS you call for '.tinymce-heading' and '.tinymce-body'. But in your HTML you named them '.dfree-header' and '.dfree-body'.

Change them to fit and after double-clicking your content your toolbar should show up.

Comment: I am trying to use the Distraction Free editor, and I do not see a '.tinymce-heading' or '.tinymce-body' in my code. They both have the same class names as far as what I can see, I tried searching as well.

Comment: My bad. I got confused when searching for the error as well. Sorry for that. I'm glad you found a solution.